# File name parsing issue with space c#

Tags: filenames, space

i am trying to merge two wave file using sox.exe.

when i am specifying small path then it is working but when i am giving big path with space in it then i am getting no error but no file is getting generated. i got a tips from this url
[C# - Easiest way to parse filename with spaces eg. "C:\Test\File with spaces.txt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857325/c-sharp-easiest-way-to-parse-filename-with-spaces-eg-c-test-file-with-space)

but the above one did not work.

here i am giving few code that how my code look like

```
-m C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\bin\Debug\VoiceRecords\in.wav 
C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\bin\Debug\VoiceRecords\capture.wav 
C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\bin\Debug\VoiceRecords\_20140506020037.wav
```

C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\sox.exe
and the above path as follows

Comment: I am not sure how programming is involved here. Where is the code?

Comment: put the path between ""(eg. "your filename with spaces").

Comment: 6k reputation and still can't ask a coherent question. Or use capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your path between ""

```
-m "C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\bin\Debug\VoiceRecords\in.wav" 
"C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\bin\Debug\VoiceRecords\capture.wav"
"C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\bin\Debug\VoiceRecords\_20140506020037.wav"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no code in your question But according to my experiences use this method for pathes including space:

```
string filename01 = "\"C:\Users\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSRAssistant\CSRAssistant\bin\Debug\VoiceRecords\capture.wav\""
```