# how to handle spaces in file names in path

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, choetl

I want to access a file like :

```
new ChoJSONReader(@"0_Target Finds.json")
```

but I tried all possible ways to access like:

```
new ChoJSONReader("'0_Target Finds.json'")
```

Nothing worked for me.. Is anyone knows please help me in this

Comment: The space should not be a problem. However, without specifying a path, the file should be available in the current directory (by default the directory that the exe-file is stored in). Try using an absolute path as parameter.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521546/how-to-handle-spaces-in-file-path-if-the-folder-contains-the-space or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857325/c-sharp-easiest-way-to-parse-filename-with-spaces-eg-c-test-file-with-space

Comment: @Markus that's not true, it will search from the current Working Directory, and not the exe!

Comment: @FatalJamòn I've written "the current directory (by default...". Of course you can change the current working directory and from then on, files without a directory path should be located in the new working directory. Also you can start the exe with another working directory set.

Comment: I tried Markus and iamCR but still it is throwing error

Comment: @SunithaBist which error is thrown? Does it work for a file without spaces?

Comment: @Markus yup it is working for filename without spaces

Comment: @Markus but the exe is not always the default folder, it's the console's current directory which could be different, especially when running in Visual Studio's run/debug mode.

Comment: @SunithaBist do you get an exception or does nothing happen at all? You could try to call `System.IO.File.Exists("0_Target Finds.json");` and check its return value. If it returns true and the component still does not open the file, maybe the problem is in the component.

Comment: @SunithaBist does your constructor accept a Stream object? Have you tried File.Exists or using a FileInfo instance on your path string?

Comment: @FatalJamòn with "by default" I meant to describe the most common, simplest case. Of course there are lots of other cases.

Comment: @Markus I didn't mean to criticize, I agree with what you said. It is indeed the most common case in Console applications. But in GUI apps, whenever you use a File dialog, I think the current directory is changed. I've had nightmares with that a long time ago, that's why it haunts me :P

Comment: @FatalJamòn no problem :-) you are absolutely right that there are some complex cases. BTW: I'm sure you've found out during your nightmare, but you can use the `RestoreDirectory` property on the file dialog to reset the directory after the dialog is closed. Unfortunately, the default value is false...

Comment: I've been using absolute file paths since then, using the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetBaseDirectory path for all my exe searches. I rarely rely on the Current Directory unless explicitely set by my own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `ChoJSONReader` handles relative filenames in a special way. I suppose it uses the folder that the assembly is located at instead of using the current working directory. You can fix your error by supplying a full path to the constructor.

If you are sure that the file is located in the current directory, you can get the full path like this:

```
var fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("0_Target Finds.json");
new ChoJSONReader(fullPath)
```

If you know the directory that the file is located at, it is better to use a specific path and not rely on the current working directory. You can use the `Environment.GetFolderPath` and the methods of the `System.IO.Path` class to assemble the path.